# "Add photos only" permission option not showing in iPhone6S, even after adding "Photo Library Additions Usage Description" in plist

Tags: ios

[image]In ios 11  new photo access permission called "Add photos only" introduced, to achieve this option we need to add "Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description" in plist.
but in iPhone 6s even after added this option in plist , i am not able to see the permission option("Add photos only") under photos privacy settings
(i am using iPhone6s with 12.4.1)

Comment: Do we really need a huge mostly empty screen shot?

Answer (score 1):

To enable "**Add only photos**" permission option in photos-privacy settings.

step1 to add Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description in info.plist

step2 The first time when you try to save any image from your app to Photogallery using UIImageWriteTOSavetoPhotoAlbum, then the os will prompt the AddPhotos only permission.

now you can see the Add only Photos permission option in Photos Privacy Settings.

This option will allow the user to save photos/videos even when there is no read/write permission(to attach photos).